# When a Google Play in-app subscription auto-renews, does it send another purchase notification (in app notify)?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

As the title says, I am interested in learning whether the Google Play in-app subscription model sends a new IN_APP_NOTIFY for each auto-renewal or if the developer must wait for the purchaseTime to indicate expired and then pull the next purchase token.  If the answer is the latter, then how does one retrieve the active purchase token rather than revive the old transaction which has expired?  Thank you for any insight that you may provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, for every renewal it will send an email containing transaction information to **your user**.

If you are using in-App billing version 2 google play notify your app about expiry at the end of the active cycle that the purchase state of the subscription is now **"Expired"**.

but from version 3 it will not send any notification to your app but  This is your responsibility to check at every launch about subscription expiry.

With In-app Billing Version 3, when you call `getPurchases` you will get a `bundle` which will not have product details which got expired.